# Inserting DataTable (that contains a field with more than 30000 characters) into a SQL Server table with BulkCopy

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, sqlbulkcopy

I'm trying to insert a `DataTable` object that I have dynamically created with a record class to a SQL Server table.

The issue I'm facing is that one of the `DataTable` fields has records that it is over 30000 characters long. I'm using VS2015 with SQL Server 2008 R2.

Below is the code I've used to create the table in the SQL Server and the `DataTable` object (I'm using FileHelpers library to create the `DataTable` object).

This is the record class

```
class MainPartsRecord
{
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
    public int SKU;
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
    public string MANUFACTURER;
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
    public string MODEL;
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
    public string NAME;
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
    public string IMAGE;
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
    public string DESCRIPTION;
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]        
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
    public string UPC;
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
    public int STATUS;
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
    public string META_KEYWORD;
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
    public string PRODUCT_TAGS;
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForRead, MultilineMode.AllowForRead)]
    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "yyyy-MM-dd")]
    public DateTime DATA_AVAILABLE;
}
```

As you can see I'm using attributes to the fields so that they can be parsed correctly in run time.

I'm trying the following code

```
var engine = new FileHelperEngine<MainPartsRecord>();
engine.Options.IgnoreFirstLines = 1;
engine.Options.IgnoreEmptyLines = true;

DataTable dt;

using (dt = engine.ReadFile(item).ToDataTable())
{
    WriteTableToDb(dt);
}
```

The `ReadFile` method reads a `.CSV` file from the disk and converts it to a `DataTable` object. Right after that I'm trying to send it to SQL Server using the following code:

```
private void WriteTableToDb(DataTable dt)
{                                   
    CheckAndCreateTableToDb();

    var i = 0;

    var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(Conn.ConnString)
    {
        DestinationTableName = GetTableName(FileName)                                
    };

    foreach (var Column in dt.Columns)
    {
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(Column.ToString(), i);
        i++;
    }            

    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
    bulkCopy.Close();            
}
```

The table already exists in the SQL Server database and the columns have adequate space

[Data table in SQL Server, columns and sizes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuQZi.png)

The real issue is that while the `DESCRIPTION` column uses `nvarchar(MAX)` when the `BulkCopy` object sends the `DataTable` to SQL Server I'm getting the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2146233079
>   Message=The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type nvarchar of the specified target column.
>   Source=System.Data
>
> StackTrace:
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.ConvertValue(Object value, _SqlMetaData metadata, Boolean isNull, Boolean& isSqlType, Boolean& coercedToDataFeed)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.ReadWriteColumnValueAsync(Int32 col)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyColumnsAsync(Int32 col, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyRowsAsync(Int32 rowsSoFar, Int32 totalRows, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyBatchesAsyncContinued(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, String updateBulkCommandText, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
>                          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyBatchesAsync(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, String updateBulkCommandText, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
>                          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalRestContinuedAsync(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
>                          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalRestAsync(CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
>                          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalAsync(CancellationToken ctoken)
>                          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteRowSourceToServerAsync(Int32 columnCount, CancellationToken ctoken)
>                          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(DataTable table, DataRowState rowState)
>                          at TecDocLib.TecDocMain.WriteTableToDb(DataTable dt) in C:\PROJECTS\AutoCon\TecDocLib\TecDocMain.cs:line 127
>                          at TecDocLib.TecDocMain.InsertRecordsToDb(String filename) in C:\PROJECTS\AutoCon\TecDocLib\TecDocMain.cs:line 77
>                          at SOLID_Engine_v4.PartsForms.TecDoc.startImportBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\PROJECTS\AutoCon\PartsForms\TecDoc.cs:line 129
>                          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>                          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>                          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>                          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>                          at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>                          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>                          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>                          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>                          at SOLID_Engine_v4.Program.Main() in C:\PROJECTS\AutoCon\Program.cs:line 19
>                          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>                          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>                          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>                          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>                          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>                          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>                          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>                     InnerException: 
>                          HResult=-2146233079
>                          Message=String or binary data would be truncated.
>                          Source=System.Data
>                          StackTrace:
>                               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.ConvertValue(Object value, _SqlMetaData metadata, Boolean isNull, Boolean& isSqlType, Boolean& coercedToDataFeed)
>                          InnerException:

I'm stuck in a dead-end. Have you faced anything like this before ?

Please let me know If you need any further details regarding the issue.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think, it is not relevant with DESCRIPTION column. Would be another columns which have 2000 character size ?

Comment: Hello Rainman, I'm giving a size of 2000 to be on the safe side in general, but only the DESCRIPTION column exceeds by far that limit (it has a delimited value of over 30000 characters long in many cases). The rest of the columns fall well inside the limits being set.

Comment: "nvarchar(MAX)" size is almost 1 billion characters :) I don't give a chance to exceed it.

Comment: Secoding @Rainman's comment. Check if your CSV parser is "arranging" your columns properly/as expected (e.g. commas in the data, or some other character that "breaks" csv.

Comment: @EdSF have a point. You should check it.

Comment: @EdSF. I've already did that. Each field is enclosed in double quotes. But I cannot manually check 100000 rows (that's each CSV's file row count). The fields are separated correctly in the DataTable object. I've checked the first 10 rows just to be sure.

Comment: What if there is a quote `(")` in the quoted text, and then comma, etc. etc? Other than that, just to do a _"debug"_ version of your db, start with just `max` on character data. You can inspect it after bulk insert then make adjustments as needed.

Comment: You can also perhaps check on the # of columns in your `DataTable` and see if that matches

Comment: @EdSF what exactly do you mean by starting with MAX on character data ? Could you please give me an example ?

Comment: As above, the theory here is that you're focusing _only_ on the DESCRIPTION field/column that you think is failing, but as noted, nvarchar(max) should easily handle your use case. So either do some logging during parsing/Datatable creation - e.g. log if `string.length` is greater than x (not just the DESCRIPTION field/column), or use nvarchar(max) for all your string cols while you're still debugging.

Comment: @EdSF I kept a track on the code regarding the records that are caught in an exception block. It seems that the longest record is about 5900 characters long. Nothing strange, considering I'm using nvarchar(MAX) on the database table. the DESCRIPTION field contains delimter characters internally, but they are handled as they are enclosed in double quotes and in the debugger I can see the whole field value with no problem whatsoever. I was thinking, could this be a character that SQL server doesn't like ? I'm using Greek_CI_AS collation on the database.

Comment: After some digging, it seems that the reason behind it may be a size limitation on the string length I'm tryong to insert on the code side, on the SQL server side everything is fine. (I simply copy-pasted the field value - over 10000 characters long - and worked fine) I tried to set an attribute of [StringLengthMax] but it as a no go. Any ideas ?